# Creating object within function

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to create object of class within function. But PHP keeps telling me, that class is not found. Class is defined in another file included via autoload. My code is:

```
require_once('inc/eet/autoload.php');
require_once('inc/eet/eet_functions.php');

use Ondrejnov\EET\Exceptions\ServerException;
use Ondrejnov\EET\Dispatcher;
use Ondrejnov\EET\Receipt;
use Ondrejnov\EET\Utils\UUID;

var_dump(sendEET(1111597719, 'eshop'));
```

Part of file eet_function.php is:

```
function sendEET ($number, $type){
$dispatcher = new Dispatcher(PRODUCTION_WSDL, 'xxx.key', 'xxx.pem');  
....
}
```

And the error is:

> Fatal error: Class 'Dispatcher' not found in /var/www/clients/client1/web3/web/inc/eet/eet_functions.php on line 14 E_ERROR Error in file »eet_functions.php« at line 14: Class 'Dispatcher' not found

Can you please help me sort it out?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Is `Dispatcher` in a namespace?

Comment: everything seems fine ..make sure the path is in autoload.php

Comment: @midz you say the class (`Dispatcher`) is defined in a file (say file x.php), which is loaded via the `autoload.php` right? if so, does the `eet_functions.php` access file (x.php)? make sure it does because the error says `eet_functions.php` does not recognize that class

Comment: @kampangala yes, exactly as you say. how should i make sure it can access that file? when i tried to move function sendEET from external file eet_function directly above var_dump(sendEET(1111597719, 'eshop')); everything works fine. so problem is only when i try to include that function in file. any ideas?

Comment: Ok I figured it out. I had to use: use Ondrejnov\EET\Exceptions\ServerException;
use Ondrejnov\EET\Dispatcher;
use Ondrejnov\EET\Receipt;
use Ondrejnov\EET\Utils\UUID; also in the eet_functions.php file. Thank you for responses!